# Read a JSON and parse the contents and display the result in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am a newbie in `scala`. i try to read a json and parse it using `json4s library`.
Already written the case class and code for reading and parsing the sample json file.
I need to iterate the `json` and print the details of each attribute's.

### Case Class

```
case class VehicleDetails(
    name: String,
    manufacturer: String,
    model:  String,
    year:   String,
    color:  String,
    seat:   Int,
    variants: Seq[String],
    engine: Int,
    dealer: Map[String, String],
    franchise:    Map[String, String])
```

### The json data and the code i tried is given below.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats


object CarDetails  extends App {

  val json = parse("""{
  "vehicle_details": [
    {
      "CAR": {
        "name": "Brezza",
        "manufacturer": "Maruti",
        "model": "LDI",
        "year": 2019,
        "color": "Blue",
        "seat": 5,
        "engine": 1,
        "cylinder": 4,
        "variants": [
          "LDI",
          "LDI(O)",
          "VDI",
          "VDI(O)",
          "ZDI",
          "ZDI+"
        ],
        "dealer": {
          "kerala": "Popular"
        },
        "franchise": {
          "ekm": "popular_ekm"
        }
      },
      "SUV": {
        "name": "Scross",
        "manufacturer": "Maruti",
        "model": "LDI",
        "year": 2020,
        "color": "Blue",
        "variants": [
          "LDI",
          "VDI",
          "ZDI"
        ],
        "dealer": {
          "kerala": "Popular"
        },
        "franchise": {
          "ekm": "popular_ekm"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}""")

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val definition = json.extract[VehicleDetails.Definition]
  val elements = (json \\ "vehicle_details").children
```

Comment: Have you tried using `circe` instead (https://circe.github.io/circe/parsing.html)? I've personally used it and found it to be quite helpful and intuitive. The [built-in codecs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/auto-derivation.html)are really sufficient for most tasks.

Comment: If you can change your json it will be much easier for you to parse it using Gson library. you just need to add one tag name type inside car there you can have type of the car that's it and then all the structure will be the same.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty close, just a few small changes needed.

First, create a class that encapsulates all the JSON data:

```
case class AllDetails(vehicle_details: List[Map[String, VehicleDetails]])
```

Then just `extract` that class from the `json`

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val details = Extraction.extract[AllDetails](json)
```

With this particular JSON the `seat` and `engine` fields are not present in all the records so you need to modify `VehicleDetails` to make these `Option` values:

```
case class VehicleDetails(
  name: String,
  manufacturer: String,
  model: String,
  year: String,
  color: String,
  seat: Option[Int],
  variants: Seq[String],
  engine: Option[Int],
  dealer: Map[String, String],
  franchise: Map[String, String]
)
```

[ Other values that might be omitted in other records will also need to be `Option` values ]

---

You can unpick the result using standard Scala methods. For example

```
res.vehicle_details.headOption.foreach { cars =>
  val typeNames = cars.keys.mkString(", ")
  println(s"Car types: $typeNames")

  cars.foreach { case (car, details) =>
    println(s"Car type: $car")
    println(s"\tName: ${details.name}")
    val variants = details.variants.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
    println(s"\tVariants: $variants")
  }
}
```

To get back to the raw JSON, use `Serialization`:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

val newJson = Serialization.write(res)

println(newJson)
```

Comment: Thankyou Tim. I have made the changes as per the feedback. Working fine.

Comment: so the result is stored in                                                                                                     
val details = Extraction.extract[AllDetails](json).i need to print the details of the json too. can we do that by doing iterating the 'details'.

Comment: I've added some code to show how to print the contents of `res` and convert it back to a JSON string.

Comment: If this answer has helped then please accept it so that others can see that it is a valid answer.